# What is the explanation that filter EQ changes "Ah" to "O"?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, speech-processing, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I recorded myself saying **"Ah"** in the tone of the note `C3` which is about `130Hz`, this is what it looks like:

[image]

Then I applied an **EQ filter** to it, so that there would be no frequencies above `1000Hz`, and suddenly I hear **"o"** instead of **"ah"**.

- I moved the filter to `700` and got **"u"**.
- I moved the filter to `500` and got **"E"**
- I moved to `300` and got **"I"**.

[image]

And this raises some questions:

1. What is the explanation of this phenomenon?
2. Is there a formula for how to create vowels artificially, since the
   above numbers are probably not suitable for every case?
3. Is there a way to identify vowels in a recording of speech, when it is **"or"** and when it is **"are"** and the like?

Comment: You need to lookup the term ***"formants"***.  Also consider the acoustic filtering done by your mouth, lips, and nasal coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the explanation of this phenomenon?

Your vocal cords have a very raspy sort of vibration -- they generate spectral components at the fundamental, and at many many harmonics going up from there.

Your tongue, teeth, lips and throat make a filter that filters the sound from your vocal cord.  The balance of the frequencies make the various vowel sounds.

When you change the equalizer settings, you are changing the filtering that is done -- and that change in filtering changes the vowel sounds that you hear.

> Is there a formula for how to create vowels artificially, since the above numbers are probably not suitable for every case?

More than one.  While I don't know them, I do know they're complicated.  Speech synthesis has been around for a very long time, so some digging on the web may be a good idea.  (RBJ's suggestion to search for "formants" is a good one).

I would suggest that if you want more than a superficial understanding for this, you search the internet for books, or for online courses.

> Is there a way to identify vowels in a recording of speech, when it is "or" and when it is "are" and the like?

Like speech synthesis, speech identification has been around for a very long time (I was a user of a commercial speaker-independent voice recognition card for he IBM PC back in the early 1990's).

There are a *lot* of ways to do this (and, again, unfortunately, I'm not an expert in this field).  I suspect that these days all of the "rules based" speech recognition algorithms are being supplanted by machine learning -- either vector support machines or convolutional neural networks.

Again, if you want to do more than scratch the surface, find books or courses.

Comment: As well as speech synthesis and recognition, you could look at how linguists use spectrograms (like the one shown in the question) - the reason that's possible is the same as the reason a band-pass filter changes the perceived sound. This podcast gives a fun overview of the topic: https://lingthusiasm.com/post/673943123952549888/episode-64-making-speech-visible-with

Comment: I suspect SVM's are on their way out. MFCC followed by a CNN is s no-brainer, but a STFT with LSTM will work as well.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding a bit on Tim Wescott's answer:

Vowels are made by a combination of an excitation and a resonant filter. The excitation comes from the glottis in your throat. The speed of that vibration determines the fundamental frequency (and the pitch) of the vowel.

The resonant filter is created by your vocal tract: tongue, mouth, lips, cheeks, etc. The whole thing is just a malleable acoustic cavity with 2-3 pronounced resonances. You change the resonant frequencies by changing the shape of your vocal tract accordingly.

If you look at the spectrum of a vowel you see a line spectrum with certain frequency areas where the harmonics have more energy. These frequency areas are called "formants" and they determine what vowel you hear. Most important are the first two Formants which are typically referred to as $F_1$ and $F_2$

The two main formant frequency for the English vowels for male voices can be found here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant#:~:text=Formant%20plots,-Diagram%20of%20average&text=Thus%20the%20first%20formant%20F,vowel%20such%20as%20%5Bu%5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant#:%7E:text=Formant%20plots,-Diagram%20of%20average&text=Thus%20the%20first%20formant%20F,vowel%20such%20as%20%5Bu%5D).

A very interesting way to look at this is a so-called "formant map" where you plot the location of the second format over that of the first.  Again from Wikipedia

[image]

This helps visualize the "location" of each vowel on the map. I.e. if the first formant is around 850 Hz and the second around 1600 Hz you hear an "ah" sound.

That's one of the main reasons people have accents: formant maps are learned early in life and difficult to change. Most Americans have a lot of trouble with pronouncing my German last name since the main vowel falls onto a "white spot" on the English formant map that's half way between two English vowels.

Another fun fact: People sound like Mickey Mouse when they talk after having inhaled helium (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRKVQcbIByo). This is NOT because the fundamental frequency of the speech changes. The helium has no impact on the glottis so the vibration of the glottis stays the same. What happens here is the following: The speed of sound in Helium is about 3 times faster than that in air. Hence the formants move up in frequency by a factor of three which sounds like a child or a recording played back at triple speed. Which goes to show that the formants play arguably a bigger role than the fundamental frequency.